# External I18n locale path (AWS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a database based translation system for my Rails app which works great except for the fact it, obviously, sends a LOT of requests to the database. I can only use cache to a certain amount of the requests but a feasable option for me is to export the translation table into a YAML-file, which can be read by the system.

The problem I have is that my app is on Heroku and you cannot write to that file system, I have to use AWS (using Carrierwave) to store the locale-files. I can write to AWS but I cannot get my Rails app to read the locale-files from my AWS-storage.

I have tried the below setting (which is just trial and error) but it doesn't work.

Application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.load_path += Dir["https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/locales/", '*.{rb,yml}'.to_s]
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :se]
```

Edit: My current (tedious) workflow is to create all the translations in the database (using database translations is an absolut must for me btw). Then I export the table to yaml into my AWS storage. From there I download the locale files to my local app and into the locale-folder. I upload it all back up Heroku again. All because I cannot write to the Heroku file system.

How can I setup my app so that the locale-files (e.g. https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp/locales/en.yml) are read from this external source? Is it even possible? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: Why don't you deploy the locale files as part of the app and refer to them from the ephemeral file system?

Comment: It seems like my response to you disappeared. Basically, I already do what you suggest (as in my edit text) but I often create new items that need new translations and I need to do that on the live version. This means I need to do the whole DB->Yaml->AWS->local->Heroku loop everytime.

Answer (score 3):

What comes to mind is implementing a cache for your database (so you don't need to use any YML files). Firstly if a key has been accessed, the result is cached and on second lookup - the i18n will use cached value.

```
I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Cache)
I18n.cache_store = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store) # or whatever store you prefer
```

One way to proceed would be to warm up the cache using: `I18n.cache_store.write({"en.some.key" => "value"})`. I guess it shouldn't be too hard to populate it from database.

The problem lies when you want to invalidate the cache. You'd need to create your own backend for `activerecord`.
[Here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/active_record.rb#L33) is the store method. You'd need to create a new backend module which would clear and repopulate the cache.

```
def store_translations(locale, data, options = {})
  I18n.cache_store.clear
  super
  I18n.cache_store.write(#cached_values)
end
```

If the cache is very large you'd need to implement a smarter `store_translation` method, that manages the specific translation item.

This is a bit of *armchair-engineering*, but with some effort I think you would be able to create a robust memory store for your activerecord translations.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It may be a useful solution although it was not the one I hoped for :) It seems like I can't solve it the way my question specifies but I will leave the question open for a while more.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, You can not add external translations directly using 'Dir'. Because it works locally. 
To workaround, you can load your external file to local system and then using Dir access it in I18n in same way. 
Anyways, the down side, to load any changes in external file, you will always need to restart your production server. So it is same as storing file localy.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with "load your external file to local system". Do you mean to copy it to my local system? In that case it ruins the whole point of having it in an external file system, if I need to add this manual fix.

Comment: Then you might need to customise your own translations method, which ll call every time to external file and fetch your translations from there. But this is not optimised way.  Also Rails translations are setup at the  time of Application Loading. So you need file to load it. I feel that, you can not do it using rails current I18n functioning without having translation file in rails system.

Comment: I am still having a bit of a problem understanding what you are writing, even after reading through it a couple of times. But I get that what you are saying is that this is not really possible. I would like to get more opinions on this and perhaps any workarounds to this problem.

Comment: He want to say that you can write translation YML files in the same way as you write your rails code. Pull it out from DB and write it down to yml files in same way you write your ruby code. And when you finish you deploy your code and yml translation files.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is what I currently do. I pull it out from the DB and use .to_yaml to write to a .yml-file (on AWS). The problem I have is to READ from AWS though. The issue seems to be, afaiu, that .yml-files are read in the initialization phase and thus cannot be read from an external path. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. This is one step from rails initialisation. So you can do this using suggested work around= Loading file at the time of initialisation on local env.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not really solve my problem though. I am hoping for something that could solve this bad workflow.